# How to run a process created in Activiti BPMN Designer with Alfresco Community Edition 5.0.b.?

Tags: workflow, alfresco, alfresco-share, activiti, bpmn

I'm new to Alfresco CE and Activiti.

I have to create a project of workflow- model processes, create forms for them and run this.

Initially I chose Activiti BPM under the Tomcat, but there I can't create forms for my processes.
Next, I found information that I can do this in Alfresco. Unfortunetly I have only Alfresco Community Edition.

For several days I found how create a new workflow in Alfresco Community Edition. Alfresco CE haven't the workflow console so I created process model in Activiti BPMN Designer using Eclipse.
How I can configure Alfresco CE with Activiti BPMN Designer?

Maybe exist quite different and better solution?

Thanks for your help, Magda

Comment: there is a nice and complete guide here http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: There is a lot information available, even look at the sample workflows which are available in Alfresco OOTB. Download the SDK sniff around and if you still can't manage it, I'd suggest a training.